# 'svnlook' is not recognized as an internal or external command. VisualSVN server

Tags: windows-server-2003, svn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN running on a Windows 2003 64 bit server. I'm storing my repository on a NAS and using UNC path.

The problem comes in when using svnlook in a hook bat file.

I get:

```
'svnlook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I have a similar set up on a Window 2003 32 bit server that runs with out issue. The two variables are the 64 bit OS and the UNC path.

Any ideas how to get my hook script to work?

Comment: Can you run svnlook from the command prompt?

Comment: @Alecander Jasmin - Same error in both environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the full path to svnlook in the batch file or add the directory where it resides to your PATH environment variable.

To change the value of PATH

- Right-click on *My Computer* to open *System properties*
- Under the *Advanced* tab click on the *Environment Variables* button
- Select PATH under *System Variables*
- Click the edit button
- Prepend the directory path and a `;`

Comment: I am using TortoiseSVN and I don't see the `svnlook` file inside the folder. The last like in the `PATH` file is: `;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`

Answer (score 3):

VisualSVN Server doesn't add svnlook to PATH environment variable to prevenent conflicts with other Subversion client. You should use VISUALSVN_SERVER environment variable to access svnlook using full path. I.e.

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook"
```

Comment: I guess but shouldn't you use percent signs like: `"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook"`

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for pointing typo. It seems they get lost in wiki formatting.